# Compiling Awesome from source on CentOS: cannot find libraries

Tags: selinux, awesome, centos

I am trying to install `awesome` (v3.5.5) on `CentOS7`. Since I could not find a repository that carries it, I am compiling it from source.  However, I am getting this error on running make:

```
-- checking for modules 'glib-2.0;gdk-pixbuf-2.0;cairo;x11;xcb-cursor;xcb-randr;xcb-xtest;xcb-xinerama;xcb-shape;xcb-util>=0.3.8;xcb-keysyms>=0.3.4;xcb-icccm>=0.3.8;cairo-xcb;libstartup-notification-1.0>=0.10;xproto>=7.0.15;libxdg-basedir>=1.0.0'
--   package 'xcb-cursor' not found
--   package 'libxdg-basedir>=1.0.0' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:279 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:333 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  awesomeConfig.cmake:134 (pkg_check_modules)
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (include)


CMake Error at awesomeConfig.cmake:153 (message):
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake] Error 1
```

However, I have install (again from source) those two libraries:

```
[awesome-3.5.5]$ ls /usr/local/lib/*cursor*
/usr/local/lib/libxcb-cursor.a   /usr/local/lib/libxcb-cursor.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libxcb-cursor.la  /usr/local/lib/libxcb-cursor.so.0.0.0
/usr/local/lib/libxcb-cursor.so
[awesome-3.5.5]$ ls /usr/lcoal/lib/*libxdg-basedir*
/usr/local/lib/libxdg-basedir.a   /usr/local/lib/libxdg-basedir.so.1
/usr/local/lib/libxdg-basedir.la  /usr/local/lib/libxdg-basedir.so.1.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libxdg-basedir.so
```

and I configured ldconfig to include /usr/local/lib, updated the cache...

```
ldconfig -p | grep xcb-cursor
    libxcb-cursor.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libxcb-cursor.so.0
    libxcb-cursor.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libxcb-cursor.so

ldconfig -p | grep xdg-basedir
    libxdg-basedir.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libxdg-basedir.so.1
    libxdg-basedir.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libxdg-basedir.so
```

I am afraid that I am stumped...

Could it be SELinux?

Comment: Did you install `xcb-util-cursor` http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xcb/util-cursor

Comment: @Gnouc: Actually, I did not. I installed xcb-util-cursor-0.1.1.  I tried to installed the above but I am missing a XCB_UTIL_M4_WITH_INCLUDE_PATH... Should I install the whole xcb from source instead of from CentOS packages?

Comment: @Gnouc: It still does not explain why libxdg-basedir cannot be found...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GAH**

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

And suddenly (c)make can find the packages...